# Creating a service that can be start/stop from ADB. (vibrate on service start)

Tags: android, service

I want to rotate the phone from ADB command (or even tcp/ip socket).
So I want to have a service I can start and stop from remote PC.

I don't know what am I doing wrong, when I "run" the application from studio I don't see the service in the service list:
adb shell service list

MyService.java:

```
package com.example.vibrate;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class MyService extends Service {
    Vibrator vibrator;
    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        vibrator.vibrate(2000);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vibrate">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        </service>
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: service needs to be started. Therefore you need an Activity which will start it.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko can you show me some code ?I am really not Adnroid devs it is jsut a specific product I need.